# Store the value of a key-value by its order?

Tags: python, dictionary

Reading about data structures and have a question.
This is a dictionary:

```
example = {'the': 8,
 'metal': 8,
 'is': 23,
 'worth': 3,
 'many': 3,
 'dollars': 2,
 'right': 2}
```

How to store to a variable the value of a key/value pair by order?

For example, how to store the value of the third pair, which is 23?

Tried this, which is not correct:

```
for k in example:
    if k == 3:
        a_var = example(k)
```

Comment: dictionaries preserve insertion order, so no need to do anything extra.

Comment: HOWEVER, I would argue that it is not good practice to rely on the key order.  If you need order, then you should use a list of tuples, not a dictionary.

Comment: The "value" of that item *is* "23", do you want to know what the "index" (2) is?

Comment: Actually dictionary data structure doesn't have specific order in key value pair. its randomly ordered when created. what the point of preserving order?!

Comment: @Oghli That is no longer the case from 3.7 on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really think you need this:

```
def find( example, ordinal):
    for k,value in enumerate(example.values()):
        if k == ordinal:
            return value
```

or

```
def find( example, ordinal):
    return list(example.values())[ordinal]
```

Comment: it should store the number 23 as a result.

Comment: No, 23 would be element 2, not element 3.  Remember, Python counts things from 0.

Comment: Why is return used here?

Comment: Because his example had it.  I assume he's going to put this into a function.

Comment: Since this answer actually does work, I'm not clear on why there are 3 downvotes.

Comment: The enumerate part worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the key/values have been inserted in the correct order, you can use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the third key/value pair. This has the benefit of not needing to create a whole list of values and is a bit simpler than explicitly writing a loop:

```
from itertools import islice

example = {
    'the': 8,
    'metal': 8,
    'is': 23,
    'worth': 3,
    'many': 3,
    'dollars': 2,
    'right': 2
}

key, val = next(islice(example.items(), 2, None))
# 'is', 23
```

If you only want the value instead of the key/value pair, then of course you can pass `values()` instead of `items()` to `islice()`:

```
val = next(islice(example.values(), 2, None))
# 23
```

Comment: Finally a normal answer. I'd slice `example.values()` though as author needs just value.

Comment: Fair @OlvinRoght -- wasn't sure about the value since they said `third pair`...but yes `values()` would be a better choice if only the value is needed.

Comment: [saZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14110861/saz) said that he needs a value in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70598748/10824407#comment124801085_70598826) comment.

Comment: Added an edit @OlvinRoght thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you need:

```
example = {'the': 8,
 'metal': 8,
 'is': 23,
 'worth': 3,
 'many': 3,
 'dollars': 2,
 'right': 2}
k=0
for key in example:
    k+=1
    if k == 3:
        a_var = example[key]
print(a_var)
```

Output:

```
23
```

Answer (score -2):

```
a_var=example[list(example.keys())[3-1]]
```

Comment: `a_var = list(example.values())[2]` if you want to create list in memory.

Comment: Then, name ONE Reason at least!

Comment: Okay, dodge that. **1)** Do not use `dict.keys()`, never. There're rare cases where you really need it, but mostly it's just useless memory consumption. `list(example)` works just fine; **2)** If you need values, use `dict.values()` instead of doing dictionary lookup; **3)** You're creating list containing all keys when you need just one with particular index, it consumes memory again.

Comment: ok, you're right. I just thought by pedagogic means. On the other hand, my example was STILL way shorter than the other answers.